# How do I move the bottom label to the extreme right in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-label

[image: SS of tkinter window]

Here's my code snippet

```
footer_frame = tk.Frame()
tk.Label(footer_frame, text = 'by .....', font = 'arial 10', padx=5, pady=5).pack(side = tk.RIGHT, anchor='se')
footer_frame.pack(tk.BOTTOM)
```

Comment: Do you want to move the whole label, or just the text of the label? Have you tried packing the label on the right?

Comment: @BryanOakley How to package it to the right?

Comment: What is _it_? Your answer is no more clear than the question. Do you want the actual label _widget_ to be on the right, or do you want the widget to fill the bottom but have the _text_ to the right? And again, if you want it on the right, have you tried packing it on the right?

Comment: I want to move the label widget to the right. And I have tried to pack it to the right using side=tk.RIGHT, it's not working

Comment: It is because you did not expand the footer to fill all the horizontal space.

Answer (score 2):

To put the label all the way to the right inside the footer, the simplest way is to use `pack` and telling it to be on the right side.

Since you didn't have `footer_frame` fill the bottom, it's going to be centered by default. And since a frame shrinks to fit its contents, the label will also appear centered.

Here's an example, which uses `side='right'` for the label, and `fill='x'` for the footer frame. I gave the label a distinctive color so that you can see where it is in relation to the window and frame.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")
footer_frame = tk.Frame(root)
label = tk.Label(footer_frame, text="by .....", background="bisque")

footer_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
label.pack(side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thx mate for the help :)